# Is it advisable to build a web service over other web services?

Tags: wcf, web-services, wsdl, design-patterns, gateway

I've inherited this really weird codebase where they've built an **external** web service over a bunch of **internal** web services just to add authentication/authorization using *WS-Security*, *WS-Encryption*, et al. Less than a month into this engagement, I'm already feeling the pain of coupling volatile components through rigid WSDL, esp considering some of them use WCF and other choose to go WSDL first. Managing various versions of generated proxies and wrappers at various levels is a nightmare!

I'll admit the design is over-complicated and could have been much better, but my question essentially is:

- Would you ever build a web service just to provide a cross cutting concern over a bunch of services?
- Would this be better implemented as web service handlers?

and lastly...

- Would you categorize this under the Web Service Gateway pattern?

Comment: Just to be fair, they have Service Versioning in there too; but it's still an abomination.

Answer (score 3):

I saw that very thing being built one year ago.  I almost cried when the team took months to build 4 web services, 2 of which simply wrapped other internal ones, using WCF and some serious encryption.  The only reason they wrapped the internal ones was to change the potential error numbers coming back.

So, would I ever intentionaly do that?  Nope.

Would it be better implemented as almost anything else?  yep.

Would I categorize it under the WTF pattern?  absolutely.

**UPDATE:**

One thing I just remembered is that there is an architecture called "Enterprise Service Bus"  It's purpose is to provide a common interface into other SOA systems.  This way it doesn't matter what the different applications use for their end point mechanisms (WCF, WSE 1/2/3, RESTful, etc).

BizTalk is one example of an ESB and there are many other off the shelf programs that can be used.  Basically, your app passes a message to the ESB and it handles sending that message, in a reliable way, to the other systems as well as marshalling any responses back.

This also means that you could insulate other applications from many types of changes to the end points.  Of course, if the new end points require additional information, then you'd have to modify the callers.  However, if all they are changing is the mechanism then a good ESB would be able to handle those changes without impacting your app.

Comment: Well, the **ESB** pattern is more suited to _async_ operations. When you're looking for the determinism of a public-facing web-service, the queuing on the bus either complicates the user experience or the API, or _both_!

Comment: @dexterous: Somewhat true.  You typically use an ESB when you need guaranteed message delivery, have long running processes that have to complete, or have complicated interactions that need to be managed outside of the calling app.  This doesn't necessarily mean that the API becomes any more complicated.

Comment: Maybe I should have worded it better. ESB complicates matters in the case quoted above because the API was designed/intended to be sync.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar implementations if you are exposing the services to the outside world and if you need to tighten down the security..check this [MSDN column](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc793961.aspx)..

Comment: Sorry I wasn't entirely clear. We have a WS-I service over a bunch of WS-I services. It's WS all the way and there's no other way about it! :(